# WebView onPause method. Memory leak.

Tags: android, flash, memory, webview

On my app I have a webview that loads a webpage which contains an online broadcast. The problem is that once I exit the app it seems to keep getting data since my free memory continues to decrease. It comes back to normal only if I close the app manually.

I have found this topic here as well:

[How do I pause Flash content in an Android WebView when my activity isn't visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431351/how-do-i-pause-flash-content-in-an-android-webview-when-my-activity-isnt-visible)

I also had the problem described there: my flash content kept working even if the app wasn't on the screen (I could hear it). Now it's fixed with the code shown there, but as I said, it keeps draining memory anyway.