# How to play .flv videos in android?

Tags: android

How can I play .flv videos in android?
Can it be played in VideoView or any other class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013201/is-there-a-way-to-play-flv-video-files-in-android-app

Comment: There is a workaround which will also allow you to play from a local asset resource, please read my answer to this similar question for a full solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications