# Android Media Player Library

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Just finished my code to use the default Media Player from Android, pretty pleased with the media player untill I saw the supported file-extensions.
No wmv, no flv etc. etc.

So I'm wondering, does somebody knows a library for Android to view the video's...

If not, could you give me a little advice how to continue...

Comment: Seems like there isn't - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013201/is-there-a-way-to-play-flv-video-files-in-android-app

Comment: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html It's old and closed question. But seems like ExoPlayer is appropriate way to do that now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) looks pretty good, wmv and flv are on their support format list, though I've never used it myself.

> Media formats
> Many audio and video codecs are packed into Vitamio beside the default media format built in Android platform, some of them are listed below.
>
> divx/xvid
> wmv
> flv
> ts
> rmvb
> mkv
> mov
> m4v
> avi
> mp4
> 3gp

Comment: Great, imported the library into my app. Easy to call + use the lib. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Am I miss something or I must install Vitamino player to use his VideoView in my application?

Comment: Fortunately someone has ported the source into github [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle).

Comment: @yorkw did this library need hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Jordy I couldnt use this library, can you help me how to import to my project, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity`. Thanks

Comment: Did this library support .mp3 file

Comment: Notice that it is hardware dependent, and crashes on LG G4

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new link for Vitamio: http://vitamio.org/

Edit: as yorkw said you can get (partial) source [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)