# Android cannot play .wmv videos files in my application?

Tags: android, video, format, wmv

I am working on an application which plays multiple types of videos in different formats like, (mp4,avi,wmv), now in my app mp4 and avi videos files running fine,but .wmv file do not run, and says me cannot play video.  Any ideas and help much appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: WMV is not a supported format (it's a Microsoft Windows format), see: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html Also not all mp4 or avi formats are supported either.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259257/android-media-player-library