# How to play .mts video file within an application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an android application for live streaming and recording from a hardware device through wifi. The hardware device can store images and video within the hardware and we can transfer these videos to our mobile application. I am getting the videos and able to download it to my mobile memory. But The video received in .mts fomat and unable to play it using android native MediaPlayer class. I would like to ask you is there any method/library available to play .mts videos . Thanks in advance

Comment: Default native MediaPlayer does not support the .mts file format. Better you use vitamio library for that. refrence link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8261864/3912847 & https://karanbalkar.com/2014/11/tutorial-92-live-streaming-using-vitamio-in-android/

Comment: thank you very much . I could play the video . But Since I am developing an application for an organization , should I purchase vitamio library ? I have seen about that in their specifications.

Comment: No,you need not to purchase .it is open source & free. Download the library from github and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default native MediaPlayer does not support the .mts file format. Better you use vitamio library for that. refrence link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261864/3912847 & https://karanbalkar.com/2014/11/tutorial-92-live-streaming-using-vitamio-in-android/

You can download the vitamio library form [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)