# How can I play .flv video in Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am trying to play Flash video in Android but it's not working. Here I used a WebView in my Android application but it has a problem. I've shown that code:

```
    WebView wbView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wbView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String htmlCode="<html>" +
                    "<head>" +
                    "<script src='http://www.exapmle.com/video/swfobject.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "<div id='flvplayer'><img src='http://www.exapmle.com/video/trusted.jpg'></div>" +
                    "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                    "var so = new SWFObject('http://www.exapmle.com/video/TrustedComputing_LAFKON_LOW.flv', 'swfplayer', '400', '327', '9', '#000000');" +
                    "so.addVariable('flv', 'http://www.exapmle.com/video/TrustedComputing_LAFKON_LOW.flv');" +
                    "so.addVariable('jpg','http://www.exapmle.com/video/trusted.jpg');" +
                    "so.addVariable('autoplay','false');" +
                    "so.addVariable('backcolor','000000');" +
                    "so.addVariable('frontcolor','ffffff');" +
                    "so.write('flvplayer');" +
                    "</script>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>";
    wbView.loadData(htmlCode, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to play .flv video files in android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013201/is-there-a-way-to-play-flv-video-files-in-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code looks a bit odd

```
"<script src='http://www.exapmle.com/video/swfobject.js' type='text/javascript'></script>"
```

I am some how sure you copied it from a tutorial site. You need to host the swfobject.js on some domain and then implement it into your htmlcode. swfobject.js makes SWFObject availble :

```
var so = new SWFObject(...)
```