# How to play .flv video in android using library or by another way

Tags: android

Can we use the library for play .flv video, i have already install some players in device. but we are not able to play the video. and i have found the error message your device not support flash player etc.

so any one describe me how to add library or play video online.

Comment: This has been asked a million times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013201/is-there-a-way-to-play-flv-video-files-in-android-app

Comment: FLV file is supported by the VLC player on google play. First check if VLC player is installed or not. if Yes play the vedio in vlc player. other wise redirect user to google play to install the VLC player. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You need Flash to see flv files. Adobe flash is no longer available in Google Play, however, you can install it manually:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html

Comment: I have install manually but not working. same issue i have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can play .flv files using `Vitamio` library. https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/

Comment: Sir Could you provide me some information. how to implement library using my code.

Comment: Sample available on github. https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/master/vitamio-sample