# Play .flv video on android

Tags: android, vlc, flv

In the prepared my application appeared need to play .flv videos. I found a library [vlc-android-sdk](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk), but did not understand how it is done. Maybe there are other ways to play .flv? Or is there an example of using the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Vitamino` lib https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/ as asked at another question [How to play .flv video in android using library or by another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139230/how-to-play-flv-video-in-android-using-library-or-by-another-way)

Comment: I saw this framework, but write that it is deprecated